# Traverse a recursive structure and add data to second last node

Tags: javascript

I have an Object

```
x =    {
            "y": 55.11,
            "color": "#4572A7",
            "level": 0,
            "drilldown": {
                "name": "MSIE versions",
                "level": 1,
                "color": "#4572A7",
                "categories": ["MSIE 8.0", "MSIE 6.0", "MSIE 7.0", "MSIE 9.0"],
                "data": [
                    {
                        "y": 33.06,
                        "color": "#4572A7",
                        "level": 1,
                        "drilldown": {
                            "name": "drilldown next level",
                            "level": 2,
                            "color": "#4572A7",
                            "categories": ["a", "b", "c"],
                            "data": [23,54,47]
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
```

Note this could actually go in any depth as I am adding new properties to the object but is speific format like

```
x['drilldown] = {}
x.drilldown['data] =[]
....and so on....
```

So suppose at a time I have below object structure:

```
x {
 drilldown {
         data [
            drilldown {
                 data [1,2,3]
               }
             ]
       }
 }
.....................
```

I need to go to the second last 'data' element of object 'x' and push new values. So based upon my example above it would be something like this:

```
x.drilldown.data.push(10);
```

So in all I need to find the second last data property in object 'x' and then push value in it

x.**second last data array**.push(10);

How can I do that?

==================================================================================

[Added Solution]

I added the below code and it works fine. I hope it is the right way to-do:

```
var data = [10,11,12];
var datatemp = x.drilldown;
var datatempvar = {};
for (;typeof datatemp != 'undefined';)
{
    datatempvar = datatemp;
    datatemp = datatemp.drilldown;
}
for(it=0;it<data.length; it++)
    datatempvar.data.push(data[it]);
```

Thanks everyone - this forum helped me a lot.

Comment: What it has to jQuery exactly?

Comment: How can I traverse an object - is there any way?

Comment: jQuery traverse DOM or maybe even XML, not objects... Maybe you can find a plugin that does it, though I doubt it.

Comment: By `second last data array`, do you mean `x.drilldown.data[secondToLastIndex].drilldown.data`?

Comment: Actually the secondlast object in 'x' and its data element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should happen if a data array contains more than one value, especially some objects-with-drilldowns and some plain values?

In every case you will have to set up a loop, which tests whether there are still drilldowns two levels further and does this for every level. When it breaks, the current level is the one where you want to add your elements.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, I'm not sure if you want the "second last" item, or the last.

But here's an example which isolates both the second last and the last items.
It then pushes a value on the last item.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        x =    {
            "drilldown": {
                "data": 
                    {
                        "drilldown": {
                            "data": [23,54,47]
                        }
                    }

            }
        }




    function pushValue(dataItem, value) {
        var parent = null;
        var child = dataItem;
        while(child.drilldown != null) {
            parent = child;
             child = child.drilldown.data;
        }
        // Child is now the last item in the structure
        // and parent is the second last item 
        child.push(value);
    }

    function performTest() {
        pushValue(x, 36);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="performTest()">Run</button>
</body>
</html>
```